# Getting directory of binary in C

Tags: c, posix

How do I get the absolute path to the directory of the currently executing command in C? I'm looking for something similar to the command `dirname "$(readlink -f "$0")"` in a shell script. For instance, if the C binary is `/home/august/foo/bar` and it's executed as `foo/bar` I want to get the result `/home/august/foo`.

Comment: @hyde `argv[0]` is not enough in this case since I need the absolute path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have come to the conclusion that there is no portable way for a commpiled executable to get the path to its directory. The obvious alternative is to pass an environment variable to the executable telling it where it is located.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe try [POSIX `realpath()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/realpath.html) with `argv[0]`; something like the following *(works on my machine)*:

```
#include <limits.h> /* PATH_MAX */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char buf[PATH_MAX];
    char *res = realpath(argv[0], buf);
    (void)argc;                      /* make compiler happy */
    if (res) {
        printf("Binary is at %s.\n", buf);
    } else {
        perror("realpath");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, although your example prints the path for the binary rather than its directory. Using the function `dirname` in `libgen.h` solves it.

Comment: According to the documentation at http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Limits-for-Files.html the constant `PATH_MAX` accounts for the string terminator, so +1 is not strictly needed.

Comment: Unlike `readlink -f`the call to `realpath` doesn't work if the binary is executed through the `PATH` variable.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative to `argv[0]` and `realpath(3)` on Linux is to use `/proc/self/exe`, which is a symbolic link pointing to the executable. You can use `readlink(2)` to get the pathname from it. See `proc(5)` for more information.

`argv[0]` is allowed to be `NULL` by the way (though this usually wouldn't happen in practice). It is also not guaranteed to contain the path used to run the command, though it will when starting programs from the shell.